# Adding sleep function in python

Tags: python-3.x, sleep

Is it possible to add .sleep() to this:

```
data = web.DataReader(ticker, 'yahoo', start, end)
```

I would like the sleep function to start every 10 seconds for a duration of 5 seconds. I want to do this because I think there is a problem with yahoo finance connection, which seems cuts out when I download bulk data. It works fine when I query just 1 symbol but gives and error such as

> SymbolWarning: Failed to read symbol: 'BRK.B', replacing with NaN.
>   warnings.warn(msg.format(sym), SymbolWarning)

Full code :

```
start = datetime.date(2008,11,1)
end = datetime.date.today()
# df = web.get_data_yahoo(tickers, start, end)
df = web.DataReader(tickers, 'yahoo', start, end)
```

[image]

Comment: The answer to `is it possible` is almost always *yes*. This question is vague and it's unclear what you want the sleeping to accomplish. You need to share more of your code for some solid answers, but as it stands, my suggestion is to put `time.sleep(10)` at the bottom of whatever loop you're using to fetch values.

Comment: The error is unrelated to the sleep functionality.  As @SyntaxVoid mentioned, without the code, it will be difficult to provide further guidance.

Comment: I have a list called ticker. Which is being passed to to pandas_datareader. I have shared the full code above as well as picture of symbol warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have "tickers" defined. One way to do it is to make a list of stockSymbols you want to loop through:

```py
tickers= ['AAPL', 'MSFT', 'AABA', 'DB', 'GLD']
```

Next, you will have to add the loop to implement a sleep timer.

```py
start = datetime.date(2008,11,1)
end = datetime.date.today()
for stockSymbol in tickers:
    time.sleep(5) #Sleep 5 seconds
    webData[stockSymbol] = web.DataReader(stockSymbol, data_source='yahoo',start= start, end= end, retry_count= 10)   
    time.sleep(5) # Sleep for 5 more seconds, total of 10s waited.
    print(webData[stockSymbol])
```